# Regular expression to extract filename without an extension from a url

Tags: javascript, json, regex

I have these two different urls

```
https://www.examplecom/dir/dir1/filename
https://www.example.com/dir/dir1/filename?start=83477&index=2
```

and want to extract the `filename` without using the lookbehind regex because I'm planning to use this inside a JSON script.

`/[^/]*$/` is what I have so far, but it only works with the first url.

Comment: Try [`s.match(/([^\/?]+)(?:\?.*)?$/)[1]`](https://regex101.com/r/5HYd36/1).

Comment: or better [`.*\/([\w.]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/ni7beO/1) > `[1]`

Comment: @bobblebubble wonder how this would work for filenames like `file-name` or url encoded versions `file%2dname`

Comment: What about `url.split('/').pop().split('#')[0].split('?')[0]`?

Comment: I like `s.match(/.*\/([^?]*)[?]?/)`

Comment: @MarkMeyer use `[^?]+` instead of `[\w.]+` but what for `[?]?` ? (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
s.match(/([^\/?#]+)(?:[?#].*)?$/)[1]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5HYd36/2). It will support the cases when the file name is followed with either `?` or `#` or end of string.

**Details**

- `([^\/?#]+)` - Group 1 capturing 1 or more chars other than `/`, `?` and `#`
- `(?:[?#].*)?` - an optional sequence of `?` or `#`  followed with any 0+ chars as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.

JS demo:

```js
var strs = ['https://www.examplecom/dir/dir1/filename', 'https://www.example.com/dir/dir1/filename?start=83477&index=2', 'https://www.example.com/dir/dir1/filename#index', 'https://www.examplecom/dir/'];
var rx = /([^\/?#]+)(?:[?#].*)?$/;
for (var s of strs) {
  var m = s.match(rx);
  if (m) {
    console.log(s, "=>", m[1]);
  } else {
    console.log(s, "=> No match!");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it is an *url*, you might want to use the `URL` and its `pathname`, and then simply `split()` it, `reverse()` the array and grab the first item `[0]`.

```js
const url1 = new URL('https://www.example.com/dir/dir1/filename');
const url2 = new URL('https://www.example.com/dir/dir1/filename?start=83477&index=2');

console.log(url1.pathname.split("/").reverse()[0]);
console.log(url2.pathname.split("/").reverse()[0]);
```

---

Or use `pop()`

```js
const url1 = new URL('https://www.example.com/dir/dir1/filename');
const url2 = new URL('https://www.example.com/dir/dir1/filename?start=83477&index=2');

console.log(url1.pathname.split("/").pop());
console.log(url2.pathname.split("/").pop());
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```js
var urls=[
   'https://www.examplecom/dir/dir1/filename', //only file name
   'https://www.example.com/dir/dir1/filename?start=83477&index=2', //with get params
   'https://www.example.com/dir/dir1/filename.php?start=83477&index=2' //with extension
   ];

for(var key in urls){
 var url= urls[key];
 var file_name_no_ext= url.replace(/\?.*$/,"").replace(/.*\//,"").replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, ""); 
  console.log(file_name_no_ext);
}
```